# SQL Job Executed successfully but In the log I can see description with error code:0xC001000E

Tags: sql, azure, ssis, ssas, cube

I have a job scheduled to run for every day which was running fine previously but for the last few weeks I am getting the below error message in the description(I have checked it in the log) but Job runs successfully.

Here the error message:

> This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific
>   connection element is not found.  End Error  Error: 2018-07-26
>   06:00:01.50     Code: 0xC001000E

Is anybody have idea where can I check this and what could be the issue?

Regards,
Priyanga

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an invalid connection manager.  If this package was made from an older one, there may be components still pointing at an old connection manager.  The reason that the package is still running is likely because either the objects using this connection are not being executed and have set DelayValidation to true/ValidateExternalMetadata to false, or they're disabled.  There should be additional error messages with the ID of the referenced connection manager, if there's not then you can track this by configuring logging for your package.  If you want to find what tasks reference this connection manager, then right click the package, select View Code, and search for the ID of the connection manager in the package XML.